# Google Sheets download as Excel (XLSX)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, export-to-excel

I am downloading a Google spreadsheet as Excel (XLSX). Everything works fine EXCEPT any cell with either `MAXIFS` or `MINIFS` inside the formula place an `@` sign after the `=` in the beginning of the cell, which causes the cell to value as a `#NAME`. Below is an example:

`=@IF(SUM(G72:G551)>0,MAXIFS(F72:F551,G72:G551,">0"),'BOND INPUT'!G44)`

Does anyone know how to eliminate the `@`? The EXCEL file is fed into a system so EXCEL .xlsx file is never actually opened in EXCEL.

Comment: Excel 2010 doesn't have MAXIFS or MINIFS, which I think is really why you get a #NAME? error.

Comment: Sorry, they have Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13029.20342) 64-bit

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a #NAME? error unless the functions aren't available or one of the source ranges contains #NAME? errors. I can't see why Excel would add an @ to that formula as it would never return more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `#NAME?` is caused by `@` as it's valid in Excel 2019 and 365. `MAXIFS` and `MINFS` were introduced in 2019.

Firts you have to use a recent Excel version. If the error arises in the system where teh spreadsheet is bein loaded, then it's very likely that is using and old Excel file parser.

Anyway, the `@` can't be removed from the Google Sheets download as built-in function. You could remove it by editing the downloaded file.

Resources

- [Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)
  Related
- [@ in the beginning of a formula](https://superuser.com/q/1471013/152004)